# Validating messages in an orchestration, or receive port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I've been working under the assumption that a message entering an orchestration was validated against the messages schema, only to realize recently that this is not the case.  There doesn't appear to be a validate shape, so I'm wondering if there is a clean reusable pattern out there to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the messages on an XMLReceive pipeline, but unfortunately this requires specifying the DocumentSpecNames which can detract from the flexibility of the receive.

A workaround is to use a custom "[ValidatingXmlPipeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nabeelp/archive/2008/05/14/biztalk-does-not-validate-my-message.aspx)" and add the XMLValidator pipeline component to it.

As per your original question, there is a [config setting](http://anantm.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/validating-the-document-in-biztalk-receive-location/) in `btsntsvc.config` under Debugging called `ValidateSchemas` when message variables are assigned. I can't say I've used this as it will probably impact performance.